# Combinations of items of groups

Tags: python

I have groups

```py
groups = {'g1': [1, 2, 3], 'g2': [55, 66], 'g3': [888], ..., 'gN': [...]}
```

I want to get pairing couple combinations from each group items.

Combination items should not be from the same group.

Expected result:

```py
get_combs(groups.values())
>>> [(1, 55), (1, 66), (1, 888), (2, 55), (2, 66), (2, 888), (3, 55), (3, 66), (3, 888), (55, 88), (66, 888)]
```

I tried to use `itertools.product(*groups.values())` but in result each combination has length equal number of groups.

Comment: Can you explain in words the logic for creating the output?

Comment: Why `3` from `[1 ,2, 3]` is out of combinations? And what should be the result for this input: `{'g1': [1, 2, 3], 'g2': [55, 66], 'g3': [888, 0, 1, 2, 3]}` ?

Comment: Each combination should have two items from different groups. So [(1 from g1, 55 from g2), (1 from g1, 66 from g2), ...]

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, sorry. it should be [[1, 55], [1, 66], [1, 888], [2, 55], [2, 66], [2, 888], [3, 55], [3, 66], [3, 888], [55, 88], [66, 888]]

Comment: Does the output order matter?

Comment: No, it doesnt matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to build all pairs of groups, then compute the cartesian product of each of these pairs with `itertools.product`.
`itertools.chain.from_iterable` is then used to flatten the result:

```py
list(
    itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.product(*pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(groups.values(), 2)
    )
)
```

The output is:

```
[(1, 55),
 (1, 66),
 (2, 55),
 (2, 66),
 (3, 55),
 (3, 66),
 (1, 888),
 (2, 888),
 (3, 888),
 (55, 888),
 (66, 888)]
```